# Unrecognizable Locale when IntelliJ IDEA updated

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

[image]As soon as I updated my IntelliJ IDEA to 2019.1.4, my locale has changed to something as seen in below attached screenshot.

How to bring it back to English locale?

Comment: Please upgrade your **Material UI Theme** plugin, If it does not help -- disable plugin and restart IDE. It's font related issue and not localisation.

Comment: Also check: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000919359-IDE-interface-encoding-problem-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a font related issue and not localisation.

Please upgrade your **Material UI Theme plugin**. If it does not reslve your issue -- disable that plugin and restart IDE.

P.S. You can also try disabling the `Toggle Material Fonts` option from Material UI Theme settings:

[image]
*(image is taken from [this forum thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000919359-IDE-interface-encoding-problem-))*